# Can't see any maptiles in app after release to android market

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-play, api-key

I recently added a mapview to my app that I have in android market. When I was testing the app  in the emulator and on my phone with the google maps api debug key everything worked. Then I changed the map api key to the one matching my own keystore. I released the app to marked, downloaded the app, went in to the mapview and no maptiles appeared... I'm clueless to why this is happening.

I do have this in my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

And I do have this in the xml file that belongs to my mapview:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="my key here" <--- This is where I've put my key />
```

Everything else in the app works great, as the overlay etc.. Would greatly appreciate any hints to what I might have forgotten..!

Comment: Have you read this: http://code.google.com/intl/cs-CZ/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

Comment: Did you add the right API key for the release certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Google Map API key for Release is not the same as for debug. Take it again.

Comment: I totaly forgot about this.. I think I was still using the debugkey or something, even though I thought I was using the real key. At least it works now :)